# Tracing in ASP.Net not working while opening aspx page in a popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace

Tracing in ASP.Net not working while opening aspx page in a popup window.

For Ex-

```
modal.open("WindowTest", "iframe", "Test.aspx?Listid=" + ListId + "&ViewName=" + ViewNm, "", "width=590,height=335px,resize=0,scrolling=0,center=1,minmax=0,close=1", "recall");
```

it is not hitting `Trace.Write("Popup Load");`